# Is there a way to monitor indexes in Oracle 19c

Tags: oracle, index, monitoring

Is there a way to monitor indexes in Oracle 19c?

I have turned index monitoring on

```
ALTER INDEX my_index_i MONITORING USAGE;
```

Using the queries below to get a rough idea when an index was used:

```
SELECT index_name,
       table_name,
       monitoring,
       used,
       start_monitoring,
       end_monitoring
FROM   dba_object_usage
WHERE  index_name = 'name'
AND    owner = 'name'
ORDER BY index_name;
```

```
SELECT name, owner, TO_CHAR(last_used, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') AS "Last Used"
FROM dba_index_usage
WHERE name = 'name';
```

The problem is, I am still unable to tell how many times an index has been used in a day, and also at what time is was being used?

Is there a way/query to get monitor such scenario?

P.S I know about triggers, but I am searching for an alternative - If I don't get an alternative, then Triggers it is!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you'd want to use the system view [`DBA_INDEX_USAGE`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/refrn/DBA_INDEX_USAGE.html):

> DBA_INDEX_USAGE displays cumulative statistics for each index.

You'd have to routinely log it to a table if you wanted to compare changes over time.

This [article](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/index-usage-tracking-12cr2) discusses more about how to use it and provides examples:

> The DBA_INDEX_USAGE view displays object-level index usage once it has been flushed to disk.

Comment: The problem is still the same. I want to get a count of how many times the index was used.

Comment: @datascinalyst That is the point of the `DBA_INDEX_USAGE` system view that I linked. Check out the documentation. Particularly I believe you want the `TOTAL_ACCESS_COUNT` column.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I overlooked this!

Comment: @datascinalyst np, best of luck!